# How to build alfresco sdk project as war

Tags: maven, alfresco, alfresco-share

I used alfresco maven sdk project to build two projects, repo project and a share one. I need to deploy them as JARs, What configurations in eclipse should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The option of assembling your project as a jar wont be available until SDK version 3.0 (which is still under development). However, if you still want to have a taste of it you could use this method:

```bash
#Fetch SDK 3.0 and install it to your local maven repo
git clone https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk.git
cd alfresco-sdk
git checkout sdk-3.0
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

#Fetch the jar archetype and try it out
git clone https://github.com/ohej/alfresco-jar-module.git
cd alfresco-jar-module
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2G"
mvn integration-test alfresco:run
```

If what you seek is packaging your projects as WAR (not a jar), you should then run `mvn package` on your project then use some tool like alfresco-mmt (alfresco module management tool) to apply that amp to an OOTB war:

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation> [options]
```

You could check this [page](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/amp-install.html) for the list of options available in the alfresco mmt.

**Note that SDK 3.0 will include this feature OOTB without any need for alfresco-mmt.jar**

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build jars to copy to tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib, my projects include workout definitions, listeners and custom templates and I mustn't deploy them as amps to avoid rebuilding the war, is there an option other than JARs ?

Comment: what do you mean by `to avoid rebuilding the war` ?